# Proving by contradiction (6/9)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I have been given a statement that I need to prove using the contradiction method and I am just a little unsure of how to go about setting this up and executing. Here is the statement:

 **If x is any nonzero rational number and y is any irrational number, then
$\frac{2y}{x} $ is irrational.** 

Thanks

Comment: The statement is true. Do you mean that you need to **prove** it?

Comment: ah yes, edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Hint: product and quotient of rationals are rational. So $x/2$ is a rational and if ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this was not true. Then, we can express $\frac{2y}x$ in the form $\frac pq$, where $p,q\in\mathbb Z,q\ne0$. Moreover, as $x$ is rational, and x is non-zero, we can express $x$ as $\frac ab$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $a\ne0,b\ne0$.

Thus,
$$\frac{2y}{x}=\frac{2yb}{a}=\frac{p}{q}$$
$$y=\frac{ap}{2bq}$$
Doing so, we have represented $y$ as a ratio of two integers, where the second integer must be non-zero. Thus, $y$ must be rational, which is a contradiction. Hence, we can conclude that $\frac{2y}{x}$ must be irrational.